# Enthought traits.api TraitList() doesn't seem to support an item_validator

Tags: python, types, enthought

In some applications, I've found that [Enthought Traits.api](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/index.html) is a helpful addition to support static variable types in python.

I'm trying to use the [`TraitList()`](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/trait_list_object.html#traits.trait_list_object.TraitList) `item_validator` keyword, but using the `item_validator` keyword threw an error...  I tried this...

```py
from traits.api import HasTraits, HasRequiredTraits, TraitList, TraitError
from traits.api import Regex, Enum

def garage_item_validator(item):
    """Validate item adjectives and reject pink or floral items"""
    try:
        if isinstance(item, Tool):
            if item.adjective!="pink" or item.adjective!="floral":
                return item
            else:
                raise ValueError()
    except ValueError():
        raise TraitError(f"Cannot put {item} in the Garage()")

class Tool(HasRequiredTraits):
    name = Regex(regex=r"[Ww]rench|[Ll]awnmower", required=True)
    adjective = Enum(*["brown", "rusty", "pink", "floral"], required=True)

    def __init__(self, name, adjective):
        self.name = name
        self.adjective = adjective

    def __repr__(self):
        return """<Tool: {}>""".format(self.name)

class Garage(HasTraits):
    things = TraitList(Tool, item_validator=garage_item_validator)  # <---- TraitList() doesn't work

    def __init__(self):
        self.things = list()

if __name__=="__main__":
    my_garage = Garage()
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("Lawnmower", "brown"))
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("wrench", "pink"))
    print(my_garage)
```

This throws: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_validator'` although the [TraitList docs](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/trait_list_object.html#traits.trait_list_object.TraitList) clearly say `item_validator` is supported.

I also tried to use a [traits.api `List()`](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/defining.html), but it just silently ignores the `item_validator` keyword.

What should I use to validate the contents of a traits list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TraitList` isn't a `Trait`, but rather a subclass of `list` that performs validation and fires events.  It is used internally by the `List` trait:

```
>>> from traits.api import HasStrictTraits, List, Int
>>> class Example(HasStrictTraits):
...     x = List(Int) 
... 
>>> example = Example()
>>> example.x
[]
>>> type(example.x)
<class 'traits.trait_list_object.TraitListObject'>
>>> type(example.x).mro()
[<class 'traits.trait_list_object.TraitListObject'>, <class 'traits.trait_list_object.TraitList'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'object'>]
```

and it gets its `item_validator` set by the `List` trait:

```
>>> example.x.item_validator
<bound method TraitListObject._item_validator of []>
```

So although there is no hook to change this validator, it does use the validator from the Trait used as the `trait` argument the `List` (`Int` in the above example, so the list will only hold integer items).

```
>>> example.x.append("five")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: Each element of the 'x' trait of an Example instance must be an integer, but a value of 'five' <class 'str'> was specified.
```

So you can achieve your goal by writing a custom trait that validates the way that you want.

In your example you want the items to be instances of `Tool` with certain properties for the `adjective`, so an Instance trait is a good starting point:

```
from traits.api import BaseInstance, HasTraits, List

class GarageTool(BaseInstance):
    
    def __init__(self, **metadata):
        super().__init__(klass=Tool, allow_none=False, **metadata)
        
    def validate(self, object, name, value):
        # validate it is an instance of Tool
        value = super().validate(object, name, value)
        if value.adjective in {"pink", "floral"}:
            self.error(object, name, value)
        return value
    
    def info(self):
        # give better error messages
        return "a Tool which is neither pink nor floral"

class Garage(HasTraits):
    things = List(GarageTool())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_garage = Garage()
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("Lawnmower", "brown"))

    # now, pink correctly fails in garage_item_validator()
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("wrench", "pink")) # <-- pink fails
```

which gives an error as desired:

```
TraitError: Each element of the 'things' trait of a Garage instance must be a Tool which is neither pink nor floral, but a value of <__main__.Tool object at 0x7f899ad89830> <class '__main__.Tool'> was specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in my previous attempts...

This is wrong... `Tool` should be `Tool()`...

```py
class Garage(HasTraits):
    things = TraitList(Tool, item_validator=garage_item_validator)
```

This is correct...

```py
class Garage(HasTraits):
    things = TraitList(Tool(), item_validator=garage_item_validator)
```

Additionally, I found that I can manually assign `self.things.item_validator` after initializing the `Garage()`

This also runs correctly...

```py
from traits.api import HasTraits, HasRequiredTraits, TraitList, TraitError
from traits.api import Regex, List, Enum, Either

def garage_item_validator(item):
    try:
        if isinstance(item, Tool):
            if item.adjective!="pink" and item.adjective!="floral":
                return item
            else:
                raise ValueError(item.adjective, item.name)
        else:
            raise ValueError(item.adjective, item.name)
    except Exception:
        raise ValueError(item.adjective, item.name)

class Tool(HasRequiredTraits):
    name = Regex(regex=r"[Ww]rench|[Ll]awnmower", required=True)
    adjective = Enum(*["brown", "rusty", "pink", "floral"])

    def __init__(self, name=None, adjective=None):
        self.name = name
        self.adjective = adjective

    def __repr__(self):
        return """<Tool: {}>""".format(self.name)

class Garage(HasTraits):
    things = TraitList(Tool())

    def __init__(self):
        self.things = list()
        self.things.item_validator = garage_item_validator
    #   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #   Manually assign item_validator attr **after initializing self.things**

if __name__=="__main__":
    my_garage = Garage()
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("Lawnmower", "brown"))

    # now, pink correctly fails in garage_item_validator()
    my_garage.things.append(Tool("wrench", "pink")) # <-- pink fails

    print(my_garage)
```